# Qt and VC++ 6.0 IDE?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, qt, visual-c++-6

First of all I was wondering if I should use Qt and Windows together. If so should I use VC++ 6.0 IDE or another one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that no one should be using VC++ 6.0 for anything at this point.  Your better off just getting the express version of 2008 if your worried about cost.

Comment: +1 Agreed: VC++ 6.0 is far too ancient for any modern C++ code at all.  Avoid at all costs.

Comment: But I thought VC++ 7.1+ was .NET and not compiled into binary?

Comment: Do you think I should use MFC over Qt?

Comment: Your confusing Managed C++ with regular C++.  Newer versions of VS still support regular C++ and are much more standards compliant.  6.0 is very old and out of date.  And no, MFC is horrible too.  <i>looks around to see when he said anything about MFC</i>

Comment: I switched to VC++ Express 2008, Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4):

Check out [QT Creator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/qt-creator)

> Qt® Creator is a new, lightweight,
>   cross-platform integrated development
>   environment (IDE) designed to make
>   development with the Qt application
>   framework even faster and easier.
>
> Tailored specifically to the needs of
>   Qt developers creating cross-platform
>   applications Focuses on features that
>   boost developer productivity without
>   getting in their way Helps new Qt
>   developers get up and running faster
>   Open and extendable; integrates
>   familiar tools and file formats
>
> The final release of Qt Creator is
>   planned for early 2009.

Comment: I tried QT Creator and really liked it, but I think I'm still going to stick with VC++ 2008

Answer (score 2):

I work on a product called ParaViewGeo (paraviewgeo.mirarco.org). It makes extensive use of Qt and we have been successful using Visual Studio 6 through to 2008.

Since Qt is cross-platform, I'll go tangential here and mention that another good cross-platform idea is CMake which is a cross-platform Make that can generate Visual Studio solution files from your code, as well as project files for other compilers, in case you do change your mind and get a different IDE.

Comment: qmake can generate visual studio solutions too: qmake -tp vc

Answer (score 1):

They work pretty well together.
I have used Visual Studio Express 2008.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) which is free, cross-platform and has a ton of plug-ins.